# How to sort array and create new array with sorted data swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a response which look like this:

```
{"subjects":[
           { "Courtship -- Fiction",
            "Junglebook-- Adventure",
            "Sisters -- Fiction",
            "Social classes Fiction",
            "Young women -- Fiction"},
{Domestic fiction",
            "England -- Fiction",}
         ],
}
```

I want to create:

```
var arr1 = [all fiction value]
var arr2 = [ALL ADVENTURE VALUE]
```

So my question is how to create to 2 different array with fiction and Adventure data separately.

Comment: By using [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) twice on your data source.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not well set up for what you want to do. It's messy and doesn't follow a very consistent pattern. It looks like you *usually* have suffixes of `-- Fiction` or `-- Adventure` on most of your entries, but not all. Some are missing the "-- " bit, and some use lower-case `fiction` instead of `Fiction` (with no dashes in that particular case.)

It also isn't clear why your data is divided into 2 separate sub-arrays. (The first array contains 5 items, and the second contains 2 items, for no apparent reason.)

In order to find all the Adventure entries and all the Fiction entries, you'd have to walk both sub-arrays, looking for suffixes of "Adventure" or "Fiction" using case-insenstive string matching.

You're also missing an opening quote on `Domestic fiction"`, and seem to mix the array delimiters `[`/`]` with `{`/`}` with no particular pattern. (If your data is supposed to be JSON, lists should be enclosed with `{` and `}`, and arrays should be enclosed with `[` and `]`.)

My suggestion is to clean up your data to have a single array of entries with clear fields for subject and content type (add a field "type" to every entry, with values of "Fiction" or "Adventure"

So one entry might be:

```
{"subject": "Courtship",
 "type": "Fiction"}
```

And a part of your total data structure might be:

```
{"subjects":[
    {"subject": "Courtship",
     "type": "Fiction"},
    {"subject":  "Junglebook,
     "type": "Adventure"}
    ]
}
```